# ARToolkit ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I am a new Ubuntu user and I'm having several problems trying to install ARToolKit 2.72.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit).

I have followed several guides on the subject but haven't been able to get it working yet:

1. [hitl.washington.edu - artoolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit)
2. [linuxforums.org - How to intall AR Toolkit on Ubuntu 12.04 (x86_64)?](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/194510-how-intall-ar-toolkit-ubuntu-12-04-x86_64-a.html)

After installing some libraries I can finally execute `./configure` in the ARToolKit directory, and then use make. Everything works, however when I try and execute `./simpleTest` in the subdirectory `bin` I receive the following error message:

```
$ ./simpleTest
freeglut (./simpleTest): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0'
```

means, that the graphics adapter driver for the first local display (`:0`) doesn't support a feature set (called an “extension”) required by the application. As I see it, there are 3 possible solutions depending on your situation:

- If you're using open-source graphics drivers, install proprietary drivers with proper hardware acceleration.
- Get a more powerful graphics adapter with proper Linux drivers.
- If the message comes from the guest system of a virtual machine, you may need to set up “guest extensions” and an appropriate set of graphics drivers to make use of hardware acceleration. The previous two points apply for the host system.

Comment: Thanks,your first solution worked. unfotunately now i'm having another problem,when i run ./simpleTest this is the message i have(but guide says me that it should be start immediately with the activation of my usb camere)
Using config string from environment [v4l2src device=/dev/video0 use-fixed-fps=false ! ffmpegcolorspace ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw-rgb,bpp=24 ! identity name=artoolkit ! fakesink].
ARVideo may be configured using one or more of the following options,
separated by a space:
DEVICE CONTROLS:
 -dev=filepath
    specifies device file.
 -channel=N
    specifies source channel.

Comment: -noadjust
    prevent adjusting the width/height/channel if not suitable.
 -width=N
    specifies expected width of image.
 -height=N
    specifies expected height of image.
 -palette=[RGB|YUV420P]
    specifies the camera palette (WARNING:all are not supported on each camera !!).
IMAGE CONTROLS (WARNING: every options are not supported by all camera !!):
 -brightness=N
    specifies brightness. (0.0 <-> 1.0)
 -contrast=N
    specifies contrast. (0.0 <-> 1.0)
 -saturation=N
    specifies saturation (color). (0.0 <-> 1.0) (for color camera only)

Comment: -whiteness=N
    specifies whiteness. (0.0 <-> 1.0) (REMARK: gamma for some drivers, otherwise for greyscale camera only)
 -color=N
    specifies saturation (color). (0.0 <-> 1.0) (REMARK: obsolete !! use saturation control)
OPTION CONTROLS:
 -mode=[PAL|NTSC|SECAM]
    specifies TV signal mode (for tv/capture card).

Comment: Please edit your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: ok i'm sorry.
The problem i'm having is with AR camera
{
Using supplied video config string [videotestsrc].
libARvideo: GStreamer 0.10.36

(mk_patt:2895): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GstVideoTestSrc' to `GstBin'

(mk_patt:2895): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_get_by_name: assertion `GST_IS_BIN (bin)' failed
Pipeline has no element named 'artoolkit'!
setupCamera(): Unable to open connection to camera.
main(): Unable to set up AR camera.
}

Comment: No need to be sorry. You made a simple newbie mistake. It would however be good, if you follow the advice of my earlier comment and **stop using the comment section of an answer to try to add information to your question**. I think it may help, if you took the [tour](/tour).

Comment: ok, anyway i marked this post as solved and create a new one calls:ARToolKit recognise of multiple markers.
It would be great if you could take a look ;)
Thanks for your precious help!!!